# Correct way to configure HttpClient when it's intended to be reused in application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, httpclient

Not long time ago Miscrosoft changed their docs regarding how to use HttpClient correctly, and now they say it should be:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Especially in server applications, creating a new HttpClient instance for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors.

However it's not clear what is a best practices now, if `HttpClient` should have it's personal preferences for request, like custom timeout delay, or special headers (auth), etc.

So, keeping in mind latest MS recommendations what is a best practices for the case when application intended to send highly tuned requests?

Comment: How many different specifications are we talking?

Comment: Well, my question was more general one, than some exact scenarios. But for the application I'm working currently somewhat like several dozen of modifications could be pretty realistic.

Comment: 'Several dozen' won't exhaust the available sockets. So consider a Client per configuration, sounds very reasonable.

Comment: This will require quite a lot of coding thought. It's require to build a cached factory + some way to convert set of concrete settings into cache key =(

Comment: Or it could come more naturally from the structure of your Services/Infrastructure.